# How do I mirror a SVN repository on CodePlex?

Tags: svn, codeplex, svnbridge

I'm the creator (and so far, only developer) of a CodePlex project.  I've writing it on my laptop, using a Subversion repository on my home network.

Submitting my changes to CodePlex via the TeamServer interface is driving me crazy, and I'd really like a simple way of syncing my svn repos with CodePlex via there new SVN interface.  svnsync or synmerge seem to be the way to go, but neither's instructions seem clear to a guy who's only ever used TortoiseSVN. And they seem to also seem need local access to the destination server (which clearly for CodePlex, is impossible)

So, could someone give simple instructions how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The CodePlex repository runs SvnBridge instead of a real Subversion server. I don't think SvnBridge has svnsync support for receiving changes.

Comment: The commit comments for the SvnBridge project claim support for svnsync. Whether or not the server to set up to handle it is another matter.

Comment: The capability to sync to codeplex requires the capability to set revision properties on revision 0 and to write revision 1.

I don't think all Codeplex project together are willing to give up all their history so you can sync /to/ codeplex in r1.

I think they support syncing from codeplex.

Answer (score 0):

As you'll find in the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication), svnsync requires exclusive (but not local) access to the destination server. This makes it unfit for your purpose, as it would render the CodePlex repository inaccessible for commits by other developers (when they come ;)).

You might consider the other way around though: always commit to the CodePlex repo, and use svnsync to keep a local (and read-only) mirror of that.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just use a Subversion client to talk to the Codeplex repository (they host SvnBridge nowadays)

See also http://www.codeplex.com/CodePlex/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Source%20Control%20Clients

Comment: Because I already use a SVN client to talk to a different repository for this project, and I assume constantly Relocating the project to a different repository is time-consuming and troublesome.